# Unable to write an apostrophe in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am really new to Javascript and this might be a really dumb question but how do you type an apostrophe in between an object?

```
const data = {

greeting: 'Welcome to John's restaurant'
}
```

Do I need to write something in front of it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use '\'. So your string sould be 'Welcome to John\'s restaurant'

Comment: [String literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals) If you don't have any other language guide or tutorial available, the MDN site is a pretty good resource. (But you should have a guide or tutorial already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \ before the ':

```
const data = {
greeting: 'Welcome to John\'s restaurant'
}
```